# Anchor tag not clickable?

Tags: html, css

I've been having this issue with my  tag that's no longer working?. I removed all of my elements from my main view using jquery remove() method before it becomes into view?. I've copied my html and css to this post, please review below.

```
<div id="social_nav_title">
<div id="left_divider2" class="divider"></div>
<div id="social_title"></div>
<div id="right_divider2" class="divider"></div>
<a href="https://twitter.com/YSL" target="_blank">
    <div id="twitter_icon"></div>
</a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/YSL" target="_blank">
     <div id="facebook_icon"></div>
</a>
</div>

#twitter_icon
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: url("../images/twitter_icon.png") no-repeat center;
    width: 16px;
    height: 14px;
    margin-right:2px;
    margin-left: 47%;
    top:-5px;

}

#facebook_icon
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: url("../images/facebook_icon.png") no-repeat center;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    top: -5px;
}
#twitter_icon, #facebook_icon
{
    margin-top: 6px;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't have a `<div>` inside of an `<a>`, that's invalid HTML.

Comment: Seems perfectly clickable to me (FF26), http://jsfiddle.net/T6RBy/ , but `opacity:0` makes it invisible..

Comment: Any compelling reason why you're using divs instead of img tags?

Comment: @RocketHazmat is right.. except on HTML5 where it is valid

Comment: clickable for me too, (mac osx latest chrome)

Comment: @RocketHazmat, [the `a` element has a transparent content model which allows it to contain flow content if it's in a context where flow content could be used](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-a-element). In layman's terms if a `div` is allowed in the parent of the `a` element, a `div` is allowed in the anchor.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I guess HTML5 changed the rules.  Because in HTML4, you couldn't do that.  `previous versions of HTML restricted the a element to only containing phrasing content (essentially, what was in previous versions referred to as “inline” content)` http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a

Comment: Well, it's still clickable if I change the DTD in the fiddle to HTML4, so it seems to be irrelevant to the problem at hand, if indeed there is one.

Comment: Hmmm, for some reason it doesn't work when I remove my main view with jquery remove() method?. And if I don't remove it, it works for some odd reason?. I read the documentation and it says it will remove all children and unbind any events associated with the children?.

Comment: Ok found the problem it was my view that was preventing any events being fired. I had to set my views "z-index" to 1. So basically my view was above my icons which prevented it from firing any events.

Answer (score 0):

For me everything is click-able but you can try to remove `<div></div>` from the anchor tags and replace it with an `<img>` tags.
 It may help you, but I can't be 100% sure, I just think it can cause some issues when you have divs in anchor links :) 
 One more reason it can cause problems is that you have opacity set for 0 in

```
opacity:0;
```

you should delete it or change it to 1 asi it is here:

```
opacity:1;
```

Comment: So I tried using img tags and opacity to 1 instead of 0 and that didn't work either?.

Comment: please tell me if you see your links there ? I mean do you see on your page these logos "fb" and "twitt"?